# C++ function code, using arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I am having trouble understanding what is wrong with my code for this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Find the earliest occurrence in a of one or more consecutive strings that are equal to target; set begin to the position of the first occurrence of target, set end to the last occurrence of target in that earliest consecutive sequence, and return true. If n is negative or if no string in a is equal to target, leave begin and end unchanged and return false.

```
bool locateSequence(const string a[], int n, string target, int& begin, int& end)
{
    if (n < 0)
        return 0;
    for (int i=0; i < n-1; i++)
    {
        if (a[i]==target && a[i+1]==target )
        {
            begin = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    for (int f=0; f < n-1; f++)
    {
        if (a[f]==target && a[f+1]==target )
        {
            end = f + 1;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What is the error (compilation, wrong result, ...) ? input, expected output ?

Comment: BTW, `-1` is not a `bool`.

Comment: Your function is designed to return a boolean value, so by returning -1 at row nr.4
`if (n<0) return -1` it will throw an error for sure.

Comment: @Ange1: Well, actually it *is* valid to set a `bool` to `-1`. No error whatsoever. However, since it's not `0`, it resolves to `true`, which is probably not what the OP intended...

Comment: I’d prefer to declare `n` as `unsigned int` instead of discarding one half of possible values by the check `if (n < 0)`.

Comment: @DevSolar  I understand what you mean, but since the OP is not explaining himself about the type of the error thrown, or what us going wrong, I may assume that by returning  -1, instead of accomplishing what he has to, the function returns true,and in the request it's specified: **If n is negative or if no string in a is equal to target, leave begin and end unchanged and return false.**

Comment: Thank you. However the issue is not whether or not it compiles anymore, but that it does not do what it is expected. I can't understand why or how to fix this.

Comment: @JohnWrgzl can you be more specific? For example, what do you expect and what it does?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to write something which is already available for free!

Please take a look for:

```
std::search Search range for subsequence
```

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

std::string search_in("abcdefhalloxyz");
std::string search_for("hallo");


int main()
{
    std::string::iterator it =
        std::search
        (
         search_in.begin(), search_in.end(),
         search_for.begin(), search_for.end()
        );

    if ( it != search_in.end() )
    {
        std::cout << "Found at " << it-search_in.begin() << std::endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: This is great but I am trying to use the function bool locateSequence(const string a[], int n, string target, int& begin, int& end) because that is part of the problem.